# DOMDocument not returning results (PHP)

Tags: php, domdocument

I am trying to find all line items with a class of "menu_item" and it's not turning anything up.  The page most certainly has 'content ' scattered throughout, so that's not the problem.  Thanks for any help you can offer!

```
$url = "http://www.examplesite.com";
$doc = new DOMDocument;

$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$results = $xPath->query('//li[@class="menu_item"]');
print_r($results);
```

The printing only returns this: 'DOMNodeList Object ( )'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct behavior since `$xpath->query` method returns an object of type [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). Try iterating `$results` object like this:

```
if ($results) {
   for ($i=0; $i < $results->length; $i++) {
       $node = $results->item($i);
       var_dump($node);
   }
}
```

Comment: Provide a small sample of  loaded HTML in your question then I can investigate further.